# Does a child class's method refers to "this", does it also refer to the super class?

Tags: java

I know that a child class automatically calls super() in its constructor method, but was wondering why it seems like a child class's inherited method also seems to call the super class's method.

For example:

```
public class Laptop{
    private int ram = 8;
    void setRam(int r){
        this.ram = r;
    }
    int getRam(){
        return this.ram;
    }
}


public class MacBook extends Laptop{
    int superRam(){
        return super.getRam();
    }
}


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MacBook mb = new MacBook();
        mb.setRam(16);
        System.out.println(mb.getRam() + "\n" +
        mb.superRam());
    }
}
```

This code returns
16
16

Since mb is an object of MacBook, shouldn't the setRam() method's **this** affect MacBook and not the super class's variable? Thus, shouldn't it return
16
8?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're thinking inheritance wrong. There aren't two `ram` variables in the `MacBook` instance `mb` (one in `MacBook` itself and one in `Laptop`). There's only that instance's variable, and you explicitly set it to 16.

Comment: They're one and the same variable, so `16 16` is the correct output

Comment: Why the child class's "inherited method" also seems to call the super class's method? Which inherited method is that? `setRam`? There's only one `setRam` function--there's no other function to call. `getRam`? There's only one `getRam` function--there's no other function to call.

Comment: probably just me, but I think this is a valid question, why are there downvotes, can somebody help me clear this up?

Comment: @wuhoyt While I didn't downvote, inheritance mechanisms are generally well-explained in tutorials--it's not clear where the OP's confusion is stemming from.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the reply, it makes sense. I am not saying nobody should downvote it or anythings, who am i to tell others do this or that, right. I think I can say we encourage PO to look the answer up from other places, know the concept of inheritance better(cuz it is basic) and then come here and ask question if still get one

Comment: Sorry if you guys felt that this was an unnecessary question. I was studying the concept of inheritance and fiddling with Java to reinforce my learning, but came across this and wished to find a specific answer to this specific scenario. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what object oriented means, at least, java's take on the idea.

`class MacBook extends Laptop` basically means: The definition of MacBook is thusly: First, take everything Laptops can do (all fields, all methods). Then, *add* everything in this definition of the MacBook class *on top of* what Laptop already provides (with the caveat that any methods you write in MacBook that have an identical signature to anything in Laptop isn't *adding a second variant*, it's *overwriting* it. Not so for fields - if you define a field in Laptop named 'foo' and one in MacBook also named 'foo', then all MacBook instances have 2 separate fields, both unfortunately named 'foo').

So, MacBook isn't "two things", where one can conceivably refer to 'the macbook part' and 'the laptop' part. Not how it works. There's just the macbook part (which is all laptop defines and more on top of that).

Note that you can only add, never remove. If Laptops have a `getRam` method, then MacBooks will also have it. You can't remove it.

That's because java is covariant: You can treat any MacBook as a Laptop. If you were allowed to only selectively grab things from Laptop to 'copy over', then java's covariance would break. Imagine:

```
Laptop myLaptop = new MacBook(); // legal java
myLaptop.getRam(); // what would this mean, if MacBooks removed the getRam method?
```

In this case, MacBooks have:

- A field named `ram`, source: `class Laptop`.
- A method named `setRam(int)`, defined in Laptop and not overridden in Macbook.
- A method named `getRam()`, defined in Laptop and not overridden in Macbook.
- A method named `superRam()`, defined by Macbook.

All macbooks have this, and it's not divided out. The source of a definition could possibly be from Laptop or MacBook, but that's just 'defining what instances of this thing have'. Once you start writing the code (the stuff inside the `{` and `}`), you're writing code that runs for a given instance of the stuff, and there's no distinction about where things came from.

### So what about `super()`?

In constructors only, you *must* invoke your parent constructor. The job of creating a new instance of MacBook is a process that starts from the bottom (`java.lang.Object`) and goes up through the hierarchy, with each definition contributing whatever it needs to initialize an object. After all, if MacBook defines a new type by saying "everything Laptops do, and more", then clearly we need Laptop's initialization code to run first and then we can add to the initialization. If you don't write `super(x)` at the start of your constructor, then java will stick a silent `super();` (call the no-args super constructor) at the top, and if that's not legal (because there is no no-args super constructor) then it won't compile. In addition, if you have no constructors, java gives you a no-args one that is `public` and has no code in it - which then means `super();` is assumed to be in it. Which is why you can write `class MacBook extends Laptop {}` without writing any constructors - java is writing them for you.

Calling `super()` isn't 'calling a method on that part of you that is the laptop part. The construction process is just like inheritance itself: First do all the stuff in Object's constructor (which is nothing - it has an empty one), then all the stuff in Laptop's constructor, then all the stuff in MacBook's constructor, in one go. The one question is: If e.g. Laptop has more than one constructor, when we get to the 'do the laptop init part', which of the constructors should be used? Thats' what `super()` calls are about.

### What about `super.getRam()`

You could have just written `getRam()`, without the `super.`: A MacBook is defined as 'everything Laptop does and more', and Laptops have `getRam()`, therefore so do MacBook instances. You can't 'remove' the method, either. You can only add more stuff, not remove stuff.

`super.` is meaningless, but legal, except in one case: If you *override* a method, that is, you declare a new method in MacBook with the exact same signature as a method in Laptop, then you aren't a second identical method; no, you're re-defining what that method should do. If as part of the code in your MacBook definition you'd like to specifically invoke the original definition and not your re-definition, you can use `super.getRam()` instead. **This is only useful if you redefined the `getRam()` method in your MacBook class**.

Only the source file itself can do this; some other source file can't do something like:

```
MacBook mb = new MacBook();
mb.super.getRam(); // nope, will not compile
```

It's possible you want to redefine what `getRam()` does, but only to add behaviours. For example, 'just do whatever Laptop's implementation of this method does, but then add 5 to the end result'. Then you'd write it as `return super.getRam() + 5;` for example. That's what `super` is for.

NB: Obviously here, `superRam` is pointless. You can just call `getRam` because MacBooks have that method. Not 'Laptops have that method and you can treat a MacBook as a laptop', nono - MacBooks ARE laptops.

Think of socrates:

1. All MacBooks are Laptops.
2. Laptops have a getRam method.
3. Therefore, MacBooks have a getRam method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient and meticulous reply, and apologize for the stupid question - I'm very inexperienced in Java. I thought that by creating a MacBook object, the Laptop object will also somehow be there, since the super constructor is hidden inside the child constructor.

But from your reply, am I right in thinking that there will be a single Object, but with components added (from Object, Laptop, to MacBook)?

Because then it would make sense that I was referring to the same ram variable, not two different ram variables in two different Objects.

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.